# How can I make multi-line AutoHotKey scripts more readable?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create an **AutoHotKey** script that generates this text:

```
==videoReview
aspnetmvc
IDCODE
TITLE
DESC
10:00
viewable online
[[

]]
3
english
extras::$url=nnn;$reason=
```

Using a **similar** tool called [Texter](http://texter.en.softonic.com/), I define it like this:

```
==videoReview
aspnetmvc
IDCODE
TITLE
DESC
10:00
viewable online
[[
%|
]]
3
english
extras::$url=nnn;$reason=
```

Very simple.

In **AutoHotKey**, on the other hand, my script looks **messy** and is **hard to edit**, like this:

```
==videoReview{ENTER}aspnetmvc{ENTER}IDCODE{ENTER}TITLE{ENTER}DESC
{ENTER}10:00{ENTER}viewable{ENTER}online{ENTER}[[{ENTER}{ENTER}
{ENTER}]]{ENTER}3{ENTER}english{ENTER}extras::$url=nnn;
$reason={Up}{Up}{Up}{Up}{Up}
```

**Is there a way to make AutoHotKey scripts more readable than this by allowing for multiline format?**

(besides this being a bit unreadable, it says hotstring maximum abbreviation length is 40)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found out [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) that you can use parentheses for multiline text, this works:

```
::vidrev::
(
==videoReview
aspnetmvc
IDCODE
TITLE
DESC
10:00
viewable online
[[

]]
3
english
extras`::$url=nnn;$reason=
)
```